# Grub windows 7 loop

Tags: 11.10, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 11.10. I install it on the same harddrive as my Windows 7. When I installing, I created a new partition in a free space that I created. In the creat partition box at the bottom, I chose Windows 7 boot.

Now Im mess-up. Everytime I choose Windows 7 it bring me back to the grub menu.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

OP seems to have resolved the issue with a fresh install

> Tried and it won't work. Doing clean install.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you've installed Grub in the Windows partition. Try recovering the Windows boot using its dvd, and then install grub in the mbr, if necessary.

Comment: Tried and it won't work. Doing clean install.

Comment: I could be solved. One way or another, try to read something about installing grub 2 in the mbr.